# Android Studio virtual devices problems

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm trying to learn how to make apps for android. I got this problem:

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139).
```

But trying to solve this problem i got all this:

```
13:33   Emulator: safe_execv: start. want to run: C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe

13:33   Emulator: safe_execv: call SetConsoleCtrlHandler

13:33   Emulator: safe_execv: call SetConsoleCtrlHandler (done)

13:33   Emulator: safe_execv: call wspawnv

13:33   Emulator: safe_execv: call wspawnv (done). handle: 00000000000001d4

13:33   Emulator: safe_execv: done waiting for child process. handle: 00000000000001d4

13:33   Emulator: safe_execv: exit with code 3221225785

13:33   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)
```

I don't know much about android stuido or coding so if you tell me what you need, how to get more info or how to solve it, please be very specific on the process.
Thanks everyone for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Android Virtual Device (AVD) sometimes makes some trouble to deploy apps. You have to install the proper tools and packages in your Android SDK Manager and could be so annoying.

You can avoid this problems by using an external emulator as BlueStacks. It's so easy to use and pretty good. You just have to sign in with your google account.

https://www.bluestacks.com

It's an easy way to start and making some apps to get into Android.

Comment: Yeah i know i can do that and thas what i've been doing lately, but I'd like to fix this so I can improve my app faster.